# Allow invalid created element DOMDocument PHP

Tags: php, domdocument

Is there a possibility to allow invalid created elements in DOMDocument in PHP? Like the following example:

E.g.

```
 $content = '<div><%if></%if></div>
    <a href="#"><&while></&while></a>';
```

As of now, it returns:

```
<div></div>
<a href="#"></a>
```

I do know that this is doing exactly what it is supposed to be doing, but we want it to ignore this, and just get back the string as it was. We use DOMdocument to add some attributes to some of the elements.

So, what we want is to have $content back with the added attributes but keep our custom code.

Comment: Highly unlikely you will get this to work, although happy to see if there are any ideas out there.

Comment: `DOMDocument` is built to work with parse-able HTML Instead of using `DOMDocument` to add attributes, you could use `preg_replace` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's pre-defined values, you could replace them with "safe" values and then replace them back

```
$html = "<div><%if></%if>...";

$map = [
    '<&while>' => '[while]',
    '</&while>' => '[/while]'
    ...
];

$html = str_replace(array_keys($map), $map, $html);

/* MAGIC WITH DOMDocument */

$html = str_replace($map, array_keys($map), $html);
```

Comment: This was the best way to solve the problem. Thank you.